# Whenever I run pod install, it recreate/update lots of things esp *.xcconfig files, not sure why

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have been invited to work on existing project. I ran `pod install` (not `pod update`) and it has updated lots of things and I am not even sure if I should push them back to the repo. My wild guess is that it has something to do with cocoapods version. Repo cocoapod version is `0.38.2` and my local machine cocoapods version is `0.39.0` (can be seen in Podfile.lock change)

Below is the list of files which changed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way cocoapods works changed a lot between 0.38.2 and 0.39.0, it doesn't happen that often but sometimes larger changed to get released. In particular this change updated the way the project and the built pods are created and integrated. That's why you see so many changes.

It's nothing to worry about, but, having some people on the team using 0.38.2 and some using 0.39.0 isn't going to end well. Make sure you're all using the same version before you commit the change.

Also, it's more usual to add the Pods folder to the git ignore file.

If just you need to 'downgrade' then you can do it just for this project by installing the older version:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.38.2
```

and then running your updates using that version:

```
pod _0.38.2_ update
```